# Remove the title field for a custom content type

Tags: 8, hooks

Is there a way to replace the "title" field from a custom content type with an auto-increment ID? Since the [Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module does not have a Drupal 8 version, is there a way to do it using hooks?

Comment: Title is a required field, Automatic Nodetitles would do this... as far as I know no ones proposed a cleaner, scalable solution over what AN can do.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your answer. However, there is no Automatic Nodetitles version for drupal 8...

Comment: Check the answers posted here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183477/how-to-programmatically-create-a-title-for-a-new-node

Comment: @Kevin thank you very much for your answer. It was indeed very helpful.

Comment: @PantelisNatsiavas There is another module https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel you can use.