# How could I check that the field's value has indeed been modified?

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

Is there a hook which could be used to execute code when a specific field of a custom content type is updated? Is there a specific hook, or should I use `hook_node_presave()`? In that case, how could I check that the field's value has indeed been modified?

Comment: I think I know what you are going for - might want to check the answers here first. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183477/how-to-programmatically-create-a-title-for-a-new-node

Comment: @Kevin thank you very much for your time. However, this question does not refer to creating a new node. It refers on updating a node's field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x):

> You can get the original entity object from $entity->original when it is an update of the entity.

So something like this ought to work:

```
function foo_node_presave(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  if (!$node->isNew() && $node->get('field_bar')->getValue() != $node->original->get('field_bar')->getValue()) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I checked it and works as expected. I have a minor question though... I would expect the hook function's name to be foo_entity_presave and not foo_node_presave. Am I missing something here? While I cannot find the hook_node_presave in the drupal 8 API documentation, it seems that the function foo_node_presave is working. Do I miss something regarding the hook functions naming conventions?

Comment: Yeah it's just another naming convention, I probably should have linked you here as well: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x